# I'v got problem with connecting tow tables with primary key and foreign key to each other in mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I have one table called 'taxanomy'

```
CREATE TABLE `taxanomy`(
    id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    type varchar(255) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id, title)
);
```

And another one called 'taxanomy_relationship'

```
CREATE TABLE taxanomy_relationship(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    post_id int not null,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (title) 
        REFERENCES taxanomy(title) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

In 'taxanomy' table i have two primary key column (id, title).
what i want to do is that to make a connection between "title columns" in both tables with primary key and foreign key but when i want to create it, it throws an error:

## 1005 - Can't create table `taxanomy_relationship` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

**WHY?**

Comment: Did you mean `FOREIGN KEY(taxanomy_id) REFERENCES taxanomy(id)` ? It's how you'd more normally express a relationship.. ps; taxonomy has 2 O and 1 A

Comment: Title needs to be a unique/primary key or the left most node of a compound key.

Comment: And you probably want to reference the id as foreign key, not the title.